# Largest Number < x?

Tags: c++, templates, math, stl, generic-programming

In C++, let's say I have a number `x` of type `T` which can be an integer or floating point type.  I want to find the largest number `y` of type `T` for which `y < x` holds.  The solution needs to be templated to work transparently with both integers and floating point numbers.  You may ignore the edge case where `x` is already the smallest number that can be represented in a `T`.

**POSSIBLE USE CASE:** This question was marked as too localized, hence I would like to provide a use case which I think is more general. Note that I'm not the original author of the OP.

Consider this structure:

```cpp
struct lower_bound {
    lower_bound(double value, bool open) : value(open? value+0.1 : value) {}
    double value;
    bool operator()(double x) { return x >= value; }
};
```

This class simulates an lower bound which can either be open or closed. Of course, in real (pun intended) life we can not do this. The flowing is impossible (or at least quite tricky) to calculate for **S** being all real numbers.

[image]

However, when **S** is the set of floating point numbers, this is a very valid principle, since we are dealing with essentially a countable set; and then there is no such thing as an open or closed bound. That is, >= can be defined in terms of > like done in the lower_bound class.

For code simplicity I used +0.1 to simulate an open lower bound. Of course, 0.1 is a crude value as there may be values z such that value < z <= value+0.1 or value+0.1 == value in a floating point representation. Hence @brett-hale answer is very useful :)

You may think about another simpler solution:

```cpp
struct lower_bound {
    lower_bound(double value, bool open) : open(open), value(value) {}
    bool open;
    double value;
    bool operator()(double x) { return (open ? x > value : x>=value); }

};
```

However, this is less efficient as the sizeof(Lower_bound) is larger, and operator() needs to execute a more complicated statement. The first implementation is really efficient, and can also be implemented simply as a double, instead of a structure. Technically, the only reason to use the second implementation is because you assume a double is continuous, whereas it is not and I guess it will not be anywhere in the foreseeable future.

I hope I have created and explained a valid use case, and that I have not offended the original author.

Comment: Can you give an example of what this would be for floating point types? Does that mean that `y`'s mantissa is smaller by one bit and the exponent is the same?

Comment: I expect more from a 27.5k user.

Comment: Did.. you try anything?

Comment: @Zoidberg: It is a reasonable question, and there is no reason to expect a user with any level of reputation to be an expert in all areas and therefore not to have any questions of their own.

Comment: What if there is no representable number less than `x`?

Comment: @MooingDuck: "You may ignore the edge case where x is already the smallest number that can be represented in a T."

Comment: Are you looking for `x-std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()` ?

Comment: @andre No! `epsilon` is the difference between `1.0` and the next representable.

Comment: @us2010 If we had `y = x-std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();` would that not gives us the largest representable number less than x?

Comment: @andre No, it wouldn't. Try it on any sufficiently large number. The difference between two representables is non-constant over the range of the type.

Comment: @us2012: it could, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 10):

If you have C++11, you could use `std::nextafter` in `<cmath>` :

```
if (std::is_integral<T>::value)
    return (x - 1);
else
    return std::nextafter(x, - std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity());
```

Comment: [x-1.0 can be equal to x for floating types, and it happens for many many numbers >= ~33554432](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cc0ae3f34df4c559275ba1290458f077-61c3814520a8d4318f681038dc4b4da7)

Comment: @MooingDuck - yes thank you. It was hasty. I understand relative vs. absolute error.

Comment: @BrettHale: Easy oversight to make, I'm sure it's all over my code too.

Comment: Yep, this looks good now, +1 - it even handles subnormals/denormals correctly!

Comment: Asymmetric `std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()`?  At least check `has_infinity`.